# Getting Projects Which Are Have No Feedback

Tags: sql, mysql

In my system there are projects and feedbacks(project's feedbacks) and i have two related tables:

```
PROJECTS(id, project_title, project_description, ...)
FEEDBACKS(id, project_id, to_id, from_id, ...)
```

I use left join but i want to get projects which are doesn't have a feedback. How can i done this ?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works on all major databases.

```
select *
  from projects p
 where not exists(
        select *
          from feedbacks f
         where p.id = f.project_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from 
projects p right join feedbacks f on p.id=f.project_id
where p.id is null
group by f.project_id
```

Comment: True logic but this one works: SELECT *
FROM projects p
LEFT JOIN feedbacks f ON p.id = f.project_id
WHERE f.id IS NULL
GROUP BY f.project_id - I am ticking as accepted answer.